# Matlab indexing into 2D array using

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, 2d

I have a 2D matrix, say M=zeros(10,10);

I have another column matrix, V=[1;2;3;4;5;6;5;4;3;2];

I would like to be able to set M(i,j) = 1 for all  j >= V(i)

I know I can do this in a loop

```
for i=1:10
   M(i,V(i):10) = 1;
end
```

but it seems that it would be possible to use some form of Matlab indexing to avoid using a loop. For example something like :

```
M(:,V:10)=1;
```

or

```
M(:,V(:):10)=1;
```

but neither of these produces the expected result.

Is there some syntactic sugar I can use to achieve this or should I revert to looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're looking for syntactic sugar, here's a sort of esoteric way of doing it. :)

Assuming the length of `V` is the size of both dimensions in the desired matrix `M`, first create an identity matrix of the same size, then index appropriately and take `cumsum`:

```
V = [1;2;3;4;5;6;5;4;3;2]; #% 10x1 vector
E = eye(length(V), length(V)); #%10x10 identity matrix
M = cumsum(E(V,:),2)

M =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Ok, now: less fun, but (on my machine) faster than any of the other options that have been tested so far:

```
n=10000;
V = randi(n-1, 1, n); #% as in @KevinRatelle's answer (but not transposed)

tic;
Vlinear = reshape(V + (0:n-1)*n, 1, []); #% find linear indices of first "ones"
M = zeros(n);
M(Vlinear)=1;
M=cumsum(M);
toc
```

Comment: Many points for style and ingenuity. Thanks to all for answers - it has been a useful learning experience. I will learn to think in parallel...

Answer (score 2):

Its hardly subtle and not really better than a loop I don't think but:

```
[J,I] = meshgrid(1:10,1:10); 
V = [1;2;3;4;5;6;5;4;3;2];
M = J>V(I);
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the loop method, and the 'meshgrid' method. I was wondering about the time to compute for large matrices (since the issue with loops in matlab is usually the time).

First, I optimised the code to look like this :

```
V = V*ones(1,n);
N = ones(1,n)'*(1:n);
M = N>=V;
```

Actually, N is a meshgrid, but it seems way faster to do it this way...

I tried this :

```
n = 10000;
V = randi(n-1,1,n)';

tic;
M = zeros(n);
for i=1:n
    M(i,V(i):n) = 1;
end
toc

tic;
[J,I] = meshgrid(1:n,1:n);
M = J>=V(I);
toc

tic;
V = V*ones(1,n);
N = ones(1,n)'*(1:n);
M = N>=V;
toc
```

And results were :

```
Elapsed time is 1.726872 seconds.
Elapsed time is 5.206657 seconds.
Elapsed time is 1.548600 seconds.
```

But methods using matrices instead of loops are memory consuming for large n. I would personnaly stick to the loop.

Comment: I've added a couple of options, including one that is pretty fast (faster than these) using linear indexing and cumsum.  If you care to speed test it against these directly, I'd be interested in knowing how it fares.

Comment: Also, in your non-loop tests, note that `M` will be a logical matrix unless you cast it to double, which will slow them down.

Comment: tried your method (using cumsum) and for N=10000, it took 0.852 second, making your method the fastest of all, about twice as fast as the loop one

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
v = [1;2;3;4;5;6;5;4;3;2];
n = 10;
M = repmat((1:n)', 1, numel(v)) > repmat(v', n, 1);
```